# UITableViewのカスタムセルの描画について

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

現在、SwiftでUITableViewを使ったiOSアプリを作っています.

カスタムセルを使って各行ごとに5項目のデータを表示するのですが、UILabelで表示すると行数が増えていくにつれ処理が重くなっていくので、UIViewにdrawRectで直接文字を描画し、そのUIViewをカスタムセルのContentViewへAddSubViewして表示することにしました。

しかし、最初に画面が出てきたときに、表示領域内の最下行に表示されるはずのデータが、他の行にも表示されてしまいます。

イメージとしては、

このように表示したいのに

---

20　　　　2014-02-24　　　　XXX　　　YYY　　　ZZZ
19　　　　2014-02-23　　　　XXX　　　YYY　　　ZZZ
18　　　　2014-02-22　　　　XXX　　　YYY　　　ZZZ
17　　　　2014-02-21　　　　XXX　　　YYY　　　ZZZ
16　　　　2014-02-20　　　　XXX　　　YYY　　　ZZZ

---

このように表示されてしまいます。

---

16　　　　2014-02-20　　　　XXX　　　YYY　　　ZZZ
16　　　　2014-02-20　　　　XXX　　　YYY　　　ZZZ
16　　　　2014-02-20　　　　XXX　　　YYY　　　ZZZ
16　　　　2014-02-20　　　　XXX　　　YYY　　　ZZZ
16　　　　2014-02-20　　　　XXX　　　YYY　　　ZZZ

---

一度スクロールすると正しく表示されるようになるのですが、スクロールが早すぎると、同じ値が2,3行続けて表示されるなど、一部おかしくなってしまいます。

どなたか、ご教示お願いします。

以下ソース

```
import UIKit

//drawRect用
public var tmpDrawData = [String]();

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, {

    //Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

    //SwiftData(SQLite用ライブラリ)
    var _myDBData = DBData();   



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //TableView Delegate
        TableView.delegate = self;
        TableView.dataSource = self;

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        //TableView
        TableView.reloadData();
    }

    //行数
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return _myDBData.getAll()[0].count;
    }

    //行設定
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCell;

        //SQLiteに保存されたデータをすべて取り出す
        let allData: [[String]] = _myDBData.getAll()

        //drawRect用データを破棄、各行ごとに新しく用意
        tmpDrawData.removeAll();

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            tmpDrawData.append(allData[i][indexPath.row])
        }

        //drawRect
        var cellView: UIView = DrawCustomCell(frame: cell.bounds)
        cellView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();

        //ContentViewに残っているSubviewを消して新しく追加
        removeAllSubViews(cell.ContentView);
        cell.ContentView.addSubview(cellView);

        return cell
    }

    //Header
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        //drawRect
        let HeaderView: UIView = MakeHeader(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 475, 50))
        HeaderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();

        return HeaderView;

    }

    //Header's Height
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50;
    }

    //Cell's Height
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40;
    }


}

//SubView全削除
func removeAllSubViews(parentView: UIView){
    var subviews = parentView.subviews
    for sv in subviews{
        sv.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

テーブルのスクロールが重くなる理由は、そこではないと思います。

```
//SQLiteに保存されたデータをすべて取り出す
let allData: [[String]] = _myDBData.getAll()
```

セルひとつひとつで、SQLiteの全データを呼び出すのが、原因ではないかと私には感じられます。それは、テーブルにひとつあればいいものであるはず。いいかえれば、View Controllerにひとつありさえすればいい。
UILabelのインスタンス5個の、テキストを書きかえることが、そんなに負担がかかるものとは、考えにくいです。すくなくとも、セルごとにSQLiteの全データを呼び出すことよりも、負担は小さいはずです。

あなたの質問には答えてませんが、テーブルの設計を最初から作り直せば、しぜん当面の問題も消えてくれるでしょう。

**追加：** サンプルコードを作りましたので、掲載します。
テーブルに、月名、英語名、和名を並べて表示するというコードです。
サンプルだけ作るのに、データベースを持ってくるのはたいへんなので、リソースにあるプロパティリストを読み込むことに変更してあります。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    // 元データ（Data source）は、ViewControllerのプロパティとする。
    var monthNames: [[String]] = [[String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 元データを読み込むのはviewDidLoadで1回だけ。
        if let dataURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DataList", withExtension: "plist") {
            monthNames = NSArray(contentsOfURL: dataURL) as [[String]]
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // 配列第1要素の配列の要素数を、テーブルの行数とする。
        return monthNames[0].count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Storyboardで設定したセルIdentifier（Cell）と合わせる。
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
        // カスタムビューを作ったり削除したりという、「ご無体」なことはせず、固定。
        let drawView = cell.drawView as DrawView
        drawView.texts = (monthNames[0][indexPath.row], monthNames[1][indexPath.row], monthNames[2][indexPath.row])
        // カスタムビューの再描画、drawRect()メソッドを、強制で呼び出す。
        drawView.setNeedsDisplay()

        return cell
    }
}

// カスタムセルのクラス。カスタムビューの設置は、Storyboardで行っている。
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var drawView: DrawView!
}

// カスタムビューのクラス。ここにテキストを描画する。
class DrawView: UIView {
    var texts: (String, String, String) = ("Text", "Text", "Text")
    private var attributes: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [:]

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont(name: "HiraKakuProN-W3", size: 16.0)
        attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // いったんビュー全体を白色で塗りつぶす。
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        fillColor.set()
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
        テキストの描画。
        let attrStr0 = NSAttributedString(string: texts.0, attributes: attributes)
        let attrStr1 = NSAttributedString(string: texts.1, attributes: attributes)
        let attrStr2 = NSAttributedString(string: texts.2, attributes: attributes)
        attrStr0.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: 16.0, y: 12.0))
        attrStr1.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: 88.0, y: 12.0))
        attrStr2.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: 206.0, y: 12.0))
    }
}
```

※テーブルのプロパティ「delegate」と「dataSource」は、Storyboard上で設定してあります。

私のいいたいポイントは、

1. 元データの読み込みは1回だけ。
2. UIViewのメソッド「setNeedsDisplay()」を呼びましょう。
3. drawRect()で、消してから描くをくり返せば、なんどもカスタムビューを作らなくてもいいでしょう？

Comment: @TTKK サンプルコードを、回答に追加しました。

Comment: 遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。コメントありがとうございます。
全く考えていませんでしたが確かに毎回全データを読み込む必要はないですね。そこの部分を修正したところ、UILabelでも問題ないレベルまで動作が軽くなりました。ご指摘、どうもありがとうございました。

Comment: コメントではなくて回答ですね…失礼しました。

Answer (score 1):

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

上記の実装が不足していることと、

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

の処理に不具合が出ていると思われます。
”CustomCell”のクラスでどういった実装しているのかわかりませんが、上記のmethodでは、`addSubView`をするより、差し替えや値の設定をする形へ変更が必要です。

下記には、sampleを記載します。

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //cellをリサイクルに対応させて生成
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell :CastamTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? CastamTableViewCell
    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = CastamTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
    let array : Array = ["20","19","18","17","16"]
    let days : Array = ["2014-02-24","2014-02-23","2014-02-22","2014-02-22","2014-02-21"]
    //カスタムCellで作ったlabelへ設定
    cell!.label0.text = array[indexPath.row]
    cell!.label1.text = days[indexPath.row]
    cell!.label2.text = "xxx"
    cell!.label3.text = "yyy"
    cell!.label4.text = "zzz"
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: 回答どうもありがとうございます。  
  
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int

  
の実装は無くてもプログラム自体は動いていたので、気が付きませんでした。実装させていただきます。  
  
CustomCellクラス内ではContentViewをOutlet接続した以外に追加していません。  
何か必要な記述があったりするのでしょうか？  
  
また、labelを使ったやり方は既に試していて正常に動かすことが出来たのですが、データ件数が多くなるにつれてどうしてもスクロール動作が重くなってしまうので、UIViewによる描画を考えた次第であります。

Comment: @TTKK "@Harawo"様が仰る通り`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`でのSQLの操作が原因だと思われます。上記のmethodは、呼ばれる回数が非常に多いのでセットする値を別のmethodでArrayやDictionaryで準備するのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。 "@Harawo"様のご指摘の通りSQL操作を見直したところ、UILabelを使っていても問題なレベルになりました。セットする値については、別の部分で用意することにしました。ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

質問の主旨からは外れてしまうのでここに書くのは不適切かもしれませんが、  
パフォーマンスの面について私からも一点記載させていただきます。
※DBアクセスの回数を減らす修正と比べたら微々たるものですが・・・。

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    tmpDrawData.append(allData[i][indexPath.row])
}
```

ここの実装を見る限りだと

> [カラム1〜5][レコードの値 x n]

となっているように見受けられますが、
SwiftDataを使ったことが無いのでもし可能なのであればですが、

> [レコード1〜n][カラム1〜5の値]

に変更した方が良いと思います。  
そうすると、例えば下記のような感じで書けるようになります。

```
// データ格納用の配列
var dataSource = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //TableView Delegate
    TableView.delegate = self;
    TableView.dataSource = self;

    //SwiftData(SQLite用ライブラリ)
    let myDBData = DBData();  
    // データ取得
    dataSource = myDBData.getAll()
}

//行数
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count;
}

//行設定
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // 〜 中略 〜

    // 表示データ取得
    let array = dataSource[indexPath.row]

    //カスタムCellで作ったlabelへ設定 ※iwashiroさんの回答をお借りしました。
    cell!.label0.text = array[0]
    cell!.label1.text = array[1]
    cell!.label2.text = array[2]
    cell!.label3.text = array[3]
    cell!.label4.text = array[4]

    return cell!
}
```

破棄、ループ、append、配列の階層を潜るといった処理が無くなるため、
多少は改善につながるかなと思います。

また、これは本当にただのおまけですが、
ラベルへの値設定をカスタムセルに任せればもっとシンプルになります。

```
//行数
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count;
}

//行設定
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // 〜 中略 〜

    //カスタムCellに値を設定
    cell!.setValue(dataSource[indexPath.row])

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: 遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。回答ありがとうございます。今回は "@Harawo"様からのご指摘により毎回全データを呼び出すことをやめたので多次元配列を使うことはなくなりましたが、以後、多次元配列を使う場合は気を付けたいと思います。ラベルへの値設定の手法はぜひ使わせていただきたいと思います。ご指摘ありがとうございました。